# Does returning a local also involve creating a temp for return?

Tags: c++

I am coming from Java where anything is reference, so I am trying to figure out the basic of c++ instance creations.

```
Employee getEmp(int a) {
    Employee local(a);
    return local;
}
Employee myEmp = m.getEmp(10);
```

Is it correct that there are 3 times Employee instantiation (without RVO)?
1 - Create a local copy
2 - Temporary is created for binding to the reference)
3 - create myEmp

Why there is need in step 2? Why doesn't copy the local directly to myEmp?

If I am going to use only Ubuntu should I count on RVO and am I correct that with RVO only two instance creation is done (no need in step 2)?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantics for function return are defined independantly of what you
do with the return value: the returned value is copied somewhere where
it won't disappear when the local stack frame is destructed.  So without
RVO, in your example, you have:

1. Construction of a local variable, named `local`, in the stack frame
   of `getEmp`.
2. Copy construction of the returned object somewhere which the caller
   will be able to access.  Typically, the caller allocates memory for the
   returned object in its own stack frame, and passes a hidden argument
   with the address of this memory to the called function.  RVO or NRVO
   allow the compiler to "alias" this returned object to a local object: in
   your case, to create the variable `local` at the address passed in as a
   hidden argument, rather than in the local stack frame.
3. After return, the returned object will be "used", then destructed at
   the end of the full expression.  *If* this use is to initialize a local
   variable using the copy constructor, the intermediate value may be
   elided; the compiler will pass the address of the actual object to be
   constructed as hidden argument to the called function.  (Strictly
   speaking, this is not NRVO, but it is related.)  Other uses, however,
   cannot be elided; if the returned value is used in an assignment to an
   existing variable, for example, the assignment operator will require a
   reference to the instance to be assigned.  The formal requirement for
   the intermediate object is there because most uses of return values are
   not as an argument to the copy constructor.

Finally, given modern compiler technology, you can probably count on the
compiler systematically eliding the second copy above.  The first copy
(RVO or NRVO) may be somewhat more difficult.  I would expect to see it
systematically in simple cases like the above: RVO anytime there is a
single return of a temporary, and NRVO anytime there is a single return
which returns a named variable defined at the outermost scope of the
function.  NRVO (and in practice RVO as well, although I don't know why)
is less likely to occur if there are several returns in the function.

Comment: Now that we have RVO and copy elision is there any need in const& technique. I mean the use of  - Employee const& myEmp = m.getEmp(10); If i understand correct there is no need in it , because the RVO and copy elision will save the copy.

Comment: Declaring a local variable with as `const&` and initializing it with a function returning a value has exactly the same semantics as declaring the local variable with the value type.  And always has.  Nothing has changed here; using a local variable with reference type has never made sense _unless_  it was initialized by a function returning a reference.

Comment: Declaring a local variable with as const& expand the lifetime of the temp object , so there was no need in additional copy

Comment: @user1495181 The semantics were exactly the same: in one case, you copied into a temporary with extended lifetime, and into the other into a named variable.  Or not---in both cases, the copy was optional, and I've never heard of a compiler which actually did it.

Answer (score 3):

Without `RVO/NRVO` and `copy elision` there is one call of `Employee(int)` and two calls of `copy c-tor`, one when returns and one when construct `myEmp`. With `RVO` and `copy elision` - one call to `Employee(int)` and probably zero calls to copy c-tor.

Second call of copy constructor without `copy elision` is obligatory, since you want to construct new object from another object (work to `copy c-tor`).

Comment: Exactly as i expected. Can you please explain why there is need in step 2 without RVO? Why dosnt copy it directly to assignment? In additional is it "safe" to count on RVO?

You comment - "or mb no calls to copy c-tor, if myEmp will not used" wasnt cleared for me. Do you mean that in case that nothing is done with myEmp than copy will not made ? if this is your meaning than its clear.